# Children's creepy illustrated graphic book series from the late '70s - one story involves a man disrespecting the statue of a spider god

Tags: story-identification, books, horror

I have been searching for this series of illustrated (I think black & white) creepy children's comic/graphic books I used to get out of the library in the late '70s. Each little book had like four short stories.

One that I remember involved a man and his son in a jungle, and the father disrespects a local spider god statue by putting out his cigar in its eye. Later on, thousands of spiders come to his hut and attack his son behind a closed door, and then him. My mom hated when I checked those out instead of "real books".

Comment: Sounds like something Edward Gorey would create.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Might this be ***[The Monster Fly and Other Stories of the Unreal](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?44268)*** (1974) by Charles A. Piddock...?

[This article](https://mcsmith187.wordpress.com/2019/09/01/the-monster-fly-and-other-stories-of-the-unreal-by-charles-a-piddock/) mentions a story matching the one you described. It also notes that it was a children's book with illustrations:

> THE SPIDER GOD
>
> Captain Billy Joe Smith is with some South Vietnamese soldiers checking out a village. A building is still standing and they chase a VC into it. A fight ensures and Billy sees it is some temple. Filled with cages of spiders and an idol of a giant spider. **Billy puts out his cigar in the eyes of the idol offending the Spider God. Years later in Denver him and his little daughter are attacked by hordes of spiders.** Back in the village the idols eyes then start to glow signaling that the god has been avenged.
>
> **So this was a book that I checked out of the school library when I was in second grade. It is written for young kids and has illustrations on every other page to show what the story is trying to convey. The illustrations by Richard Maccabe are crude but effective in visualizing the story.** I still vividly remember the drilling to Hell and meeting the Devil and the human zoo. The stories were quite effective on a young mind that I still remembered them after all these years and decided to search out this book. An enjoyable nostalgic trip back to my childhood.

Comment: For non-americans, wikipedia says second grade is 7-8years old. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ivana: Could be as young as six when beginning second grade, but yes.

Comment: @Ivana  In the USA Grade (elementary/primary)  School usually starts at about age 6 to 7 in first grade and ends at about age 11 to 12 in 6th grade.  The oldest kids in a grade might be almost a year older than the youngest, and most have a birthday during the nine months of school.  And some kids skip grades and some are held back.

Comment: @Ivana School districts will consider when in the year your child's birthday falls when deciding when to place them in kindergarten. In 32 states, if they are five years old by September 1, they are ready to start kindergarten that year. Some other states have a different date, such as August 1 or August 15. [State by state rules here](https://www.superpages.com/em/age-to-start-kindergarten-by-state/).

Comment: Ah yes the classic children's literature setting of _checks notes_ the Vietnam war

Comment: Vietnam war, soldiers in villages, spider god, and a horde of spiders attacking a young child. I had to ask about the age bracket, because I didn't believe any one of these themes would be found in a children's book for 7 year olds.